# How nonlocal keyword works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures, python-nonlocal

In the below code,

```
def makeAverage():
    series = []
    def average(newValue):
        series.append(newValue)
        total = sum(series)
        return total/len(series)
    return average
```

python interpreter does not expect `series` to be `nonlocal` in `average()`.

But in the below code

```
def makeAverage():
    count = 0
    total = 0
    def average(newValue):
        nonlocal count, total
        count += 1
        total += newValue
        return total/count
    return average
```

**Question:**

Why python interpreter expects `count` & `total` declared `nonlocal` in `average()`?

Comment: The same way `makeAverage` would expect them to be `global` if you were doing `count += 1` in `makeAverage`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variable is considered local to a function if you *assign* to it anywhere in that function and you don't mark it otherwise (with `global` or `nonlocal`).  In your first example, there is no assignment to `series` inside `average`, so it is not considered local to `average`, so the version from the enclosing function is used.  In the second example, there are assignments to `total` and `count` inside `average`, so they need to be marked `nonlocal` to access them from the enclosing function.  (Otherwise you will get an UnboundLocalError because `average` tries to read their values before assigning to them for the first time.)